# Java - Converting String into instance of interface

Tags: java, interface

Working with the Filter Design pattern.

I have a Context interface, there are concrete classes implementing this interface, called f.e. BehavioralPurpose and StructuralPurpose.

What I'm currently trying to achieve is that when I add CreationalPurpose class, and give it as an option in the front-end, everything will continue working smoothly (filtering)

I have a jsp that will return a value like 'structural', 'behavioral' etc.

But now I will need to create an instance of the StructuralPurpose class. Like `Context context= new StructuralPurpose();` But I do not know if I will get 'structural' or 'behavioral' and I do not want to solve this by adding if statements, mainly because, if someone would add a new Purpose class, that person does not have to add another if statement to this filter.

So is this possible? I was thinking about maybe having a string called purposeString and solving the issue like so:

```
String purpose = purposeString + "Purpose";
Context context = Class.forName(purpose).newInstance();
```

But this will result into an error saying: Type mismatch: cannot convert from capture#1-of ? to Context

So is there any way this is possible?

With a cast of `(Context) Class.forName(purpose).newInstance();` I will get a ClassNotFoundException. The classes are in different packages, not sure if this matters. Here is the code i used:

```
    String behav = "filter.Behavioral";
    String purpo = behav+"Purpose";
    Context behavioral = null;
    try {
        behavioral = (Context) Class.forName(purpo).newInstance();
    } catch (InstantiationException e) {
        System.out.println("\n basically failed");
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        System.out.println("\n not allowed");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("\n not found");
    }
```

Just for testing purposes only, this code will return 'not found'.

Comment: Add a cast: `Context context = (Context) Class.forName(purpose).newInstance();`

Comment: Edited the question because comment would become too long, giving ClassNotFoundException

Comment: `Class.forName` expects the fully qualified class name, not just the class name.

Comment: the BehavioralPurpose class is in a package called 'filter' but having "filter.Behavioral" for String behav does not change the outcome

Comment: Alright it did work after a little struggle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, this is not a good practice to allow user to dynamically create objects like this, unless you have a limited number of situations & you have exact control over all aspects and possible exceptions.
Anyway, if you have enough reasons to do this, you just need to cast it:

```
try
{

    String purpose = "com.path.to.your.package." + purposeString + "Purpose";
    Context context = (Context) Class.forName(purpose).newInstance();
}
catch(ClassNotFoundException ex)
{
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```